# Is this Correct way to add FocusListener to JTextFields in java?

Tags: java, swing, focus

I got hundreds of `JTextFields` in my application in Java and I want to add `FocusListener` on all of these to **set Horizontal Alignment** of text and **add FocusListener** on each of these textfields. So, I made this method and it's working great. But I just wanted to know if this correct way or there is something wrong in it or I am going against some kind of rule of OOPs?

Here is the code

```
public void CreateFocusListenerForFields(JTextField txt)
{
    txt.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    txt.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(!NumberUtils.isNumber(txt.getText()))
            {
                txt.setBackground(new Color(254,157,157));
                txt.requestFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                txt.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And apply this method on my textfields

```
CreateFocusListenerForFields(MyTextField);
```

Now when I run code, it works great just wanted to know if this correct or not and if not then what is the other way out when you have to set alignment and focuslistener on hundreds of fields? Thanks for your kind advice.

Comment: Myself, I'd use a higher level construct such as an [input verifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), *not* a FocusListener for this situation since this is exactly what you're trying to do: verify that input is correct.

Comment: Also, I'm surprised that your code even compiles, since you haven't  marked the txt parameter final and are using it inside of an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Ok Let me see that and will come back after learning and understand, Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels that looks good. Yes that's the fact.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I read your provided link but didn't find any advantage of using this over FocusListener. Am I wrong? While on other side using my suggested way, I can also **setHorizontalAlignment** along with validation through FocusListener.

Comment: 1. `if(!NumberUtils.isNumber(txt.getText()))` == JFormattedTextField, maybe JSpinner is better in some specifics case, 2. `I got hundreds of JTextFields` == use JTable, there you have to override getColumnClass with correct datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, my bias is to use an InputVerifier instead of a FocusListener, if only because the InputVerifier is a higher level construct, and it always seems safer to me to use these in place of lower level (closer to the metal) constructs where applicable.

An example of both:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class TestFieldVerification {
   public static final Color ERROR_COLOR = new Color(254,157,157);
   private static final int COLS = 8;
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField verifiedField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private JTextField focusCheckedField = new JTextField(COLS);
   private Color defaultBackground = null;

   public TestFieldVerification() {
      verifiedField.setInputVerifier(new MyVerfier(this));
      focusCheckedField.addFocusListener(new MyFocusCheck(this));

      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("With InputVerfier:"));
      mainPanel.add(verifiedField);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("With FocusListener:"));
      mainPanel.add(focusCheckedField);
   }

   public boolean verifyText(String text) {
      try {
         Integer.parseInt(text);
         return true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public void setFieldBackground(JComponent component, boolean verified) {
      if (defaultBackground == null) {
         defaultBackground = component.getBackground();
      }
      Color bg = verified ? defaultBackground : ERROR_COLOR;
      component.setBackground(bg);
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyVerifier");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestFieldVerification().getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyVerfier extends InputVerifier {
   private TestFieldVerification gui;

   public MyVerfier(TestFieldVerification gui) {
      this.gui = gui;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
      gui.setFieldBackground(input, super.shouldYieldFocus(input));
      return super.shouldYieldFocus(input);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
      String text = ((JTextComponent) input).getText();
      return gui.verifyText(text);
   }

}

class MyFocusCheck extends FocusAdapter {
   private TestFieldVerification gui;

   public MyFocusCheck(TestFieldVerification gui) {
      this.gui = gui;
   }

   @Override
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
      JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getSource();
      String text = textComp.getText();
      boolean verified = gui.verifyText(text);
      gui.setFieldBackground(textComp, verified);
      if (!verified) {
         textComp.requestFocusInWindow();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Both of your answers were great but your answer taught me a new lesson and you gave a good comparison as well. Thanks Eels.

Comment: Man the great thing about InputVarifier is that it doesn't lose focus until the field is verified while when we use FocusListener, somehow the field lose the focus and gain the focus back if it is not varified and that's very horrible if you are doing calculations on fields like me. Thanks Hovercraft. I don't know what's your real name is.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a factory class which I then used to create all my text fields - I think this is a bit more "doing-it-right OOP", e.g.:

```
public class MyTextFieldFactory {
    private static final FocusListener defaultFocusListener = new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // Your code ...
        }
    };

    public static JTextField createDefaultTextField() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        textField.addFocusListener(defaultFocusListener);
        return textField;
    }
}
```

Then create all my text fields with:

```
JTextField myNewTextField = MyTextFieldFactory.createDefaultTextField();
```

This also has the advantage that you only create one instance of the focus listener rather than a new one for every text field.

Comment: Yes, I think this a better approach. let's see if anyone else suggest better than yours.

Comment: @JavaDrunk As said above, a `FocusListener` for a `JTextField` it probably not the right approach no matter how you look at it.